# Asp.Net MVC - Routing issue with same name controllers?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-areas

The problem I'm facing is that I have 2 controllers with the same name. One in the main controller folder, and the other in the controller folder in my Admin Area.

Calling the action result directly works fine:

```
MySite/Admin/Account/GetAccount?userId=1
```

Calling through the route doesn't work

```
MySite/Admin/User/1/Account
```

Any idea What I'm doing wrong?

**Application_Start**

```
AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas()
```

**RouteConfig**

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, // Parameter defaults
        new[] { "MyCompany.Controllers" }
    );
}
```

**AdminAreaRegistration**

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
{
    context.MapRoute(
        "Admin_default",
        "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );

    context.MapRoute(
        "GetUserAccount",
        "Admin/User/{userId}/Account",
        new { controller = "Account", action = "GetAccount" },
        new[] { "MyCompany.Areas.Admin.Controllers" }
    );
}
```

**My Action Result In Areas/Admin/AccountController**

```
public ActionResult GetAccount(string userId)
{
    // return Account Type
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you should change the positions of the account and check again

```
 context.MapRoute(
        "GetUserAccount",
        "Admin/User/{userId}/Account",
        new { controller = "Account", action = "GetAccount" },
        new[] { "MyCompany.Areas.Admin.Controllers" }
    );
context.MapRoute(
        "Admin_default",
        "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

Comment: MAGIC, Can you explain why this fixed the problem?

Comment: MySite/Admin/User/1/Account is also a route of type 
Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}

Comment: dont forget to mark as answer if this fixed your problem.. this may help others coming to this site